# Two lines and their Polygonal line

Tags: geometry

Two lines are drawn through a point $'A'$ at an Angle $30$$^{\circ}$ degree. A point $'B'$ is taken on  one of them at a distance $'a'$ from the point $'A'$. A perpendicular is drawn from the point $'B'$ to the other line and another perpendicular is drawn from its foot to meet $AB$ at another point from where the similar process is repeated indefinitely. Find the length of the resulting $Polygonal-Line$.

The Diagram that comes to my mind is as follows , but i dont know if its wrong or right !

[image]

Comment: Questions that are simply problem statements copied to the website are rarely well-received. Is there anything you personally can say about the problem?

Comment: Is it $\frac {a}{2-\sqrt {3}} $

Comment: Please Explain to me your solution . I dont know the answer yet, Will Provide it as soon as i get it.